# Redirecting a dynamic URL to another dynamic URL using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect a dynamic URL which is as follows:

http://example.com/manage/billing/invoice/all/viewinvoice.php?id=1541

and I need it to redirect to:

http://example.com/manage/billing/invoice/1541/

I want to do this using .htaccess

I got as far as this but I cannot seem to get it to work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /manage/billing/invoice/all/viewinvoice\.php\?id=([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /manage/billing/invoice/all/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*?)/all/viewinvoice\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)&? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*?/invoice)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/all/viewinvoice.php?id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: This seems to be the right direction, but it also seems to be adding this to the end of the URL:
    /manage/billing/invoice/1541%20HTTP/1.1/

so I need to remove the %20HTTP/1.1 to get a correctly formatted URL. Any ideas why it is adding this?

Comment: @user2715969 Ah, my bad. The bit at the end needs to be `([^&\s]+)&?`.

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks!